# NextJS get hostname in component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I'm implementing i18n on my NextJS site and am trying to add the `hreflang` meta tags in the head as advised by NextJS and Google:

- https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/i18n-routing#search-engine-optimization
- https://developers.google.com/search/docs/advanced/crawling/localized-versions

I have a custom `<Head />` component which is imported into my layout component and is used sitewide.

The url given in the `href` attribute of the meta tag needs to be fully qualified, i.e. `https://www.mywebsite.com/page123` not `/page123`. I can get the `pathname` using the `useRouter()` hook but I don't know how to get protocol/host/origin etc.

Obviously this needs to happen server side so that that the meta tags are rendered in the response from the server.

My current code (without fully qualified urls):

```
import Head from "next/head";
import { useRouter } from "next/router";

const MyAppHead = () => {
  const { locales, asPath } = useRouter();

  return (
    <Head>
      {locales.map((locale, index) => (
        <link
          key={index}
          href={`/${locale}`}${asPath}`}
          hrefLang={locale}
          rel="alternate"
        />
      ))}
    </Head>
  );
};

export default MyAppHead;
```

I'm happy to take a completely different approach if that's what's necessary.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: I ended up using process.env.DOMAIN_NAME

Comment: Where are you deploying it? On Vercel, you can use `process.env.VERCEL_URL`. If on Netlify, you can refer this - https://docs.netlify.com/configure-builds/environment-variables/#deploy-urls-and-metadata. Alternatively, you can use https://github.com/jakeburden/next-absolute-url.